# Table getting appended on top of each other on click of button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I am having and input field where I am entering the ID and calling a function on click of a button and the content with that corresponding ID is fetched from csv file and gets populated in  the table. The issue is when I am entering ID again in input field, I want previous table to get destroyed and new table has to be created corresponding to that ID, but the new table gets appended below the existing one. How can i fix it?

```html
 <div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
        <table id="data" class="main-table" style= "display: none;"></table>
    </div>
```

```js
function buildrow1(){
////////////////TABLE BUILD//////////// 

var table = document.getElementById("data");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML="<td>Item1</td>";   
////////////////TABLE BUILD////////////


    //HPlans creating the columns for row
    
var l;
var m;
for (l = 0; l < pid.length; l++) {
    
    for(m=0; m < hmoplans_all ["data"].length; m++){
        if(hmoplans_all["data"][m]["Provider ID"]!==null){
        if(pid[l]==hmoplans_all["data"][m]["Provider ID"]){
        hmofirst_row="<td>"+hmoplans_all["data"][m]["Emp"]+"</td>";
        
            var table = document.getElementById("data");
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML=hmofirst_row;
            //$("#data").append(hmofirst_row);  
        }
        }

        }
}
    //WPlans creating the columns for row
var j;
var k;
for (j = 0; j < bid.length; j++) {
    
    for(k=0; k < wplans_all ["data"].length; k++){
        if(wplans_all["data"][k]["Broker ID"]!==null){
        if(bid[j]==wplans_all["data"][k]["Broker ID"] || pid[j]==wplans_all["data"][k]["Provider ID"]){
        first_row="<td>"+wplans_all["data"][k]["Emp"]+"</td>";
        
            var table = document.getElementById("data");
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML=first_row;
    
        }
        }

    }

}
    
    buildrow2();
}
```

Comment: show js/jquery code as well.

Comment: okay i have updated the JS aswell

Comment: Did you clear the table first?  Or is that what you're asking, how to [`empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) the table.   Did you mean to tag this jquery as you're not using jquery?

Comment: use : `table.innerHTML =""`

Comment: Basically I want to clear the table and create new table everytime i enter new ID into input box and click the button to build a new table. But right now new table is being formed below the existing one. I dont need that

Answer (score 1):

As you call the function to create a table, your first line of code to be executed should be setting the innerHTML = " ".  By so doing, each time the function is called, it first clears the the table before creating another table.